# the pairplot data is not plotting correctly

Tags: seaborn

Question:
I have this code and it gives me an error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'

Any suggestions? 
Thank you so much!

```
import seaborn as sns
features = ['rdeep','dtc','rhob', 'gr','npss']
feature_vectors=df[features]

feature_vectors = feature_vectors.apply(np.nan_to_num)
feature_vectors.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
feature_vectors
sns.pairplot(feature_vectors, dropna=True )
```

Here is the fullstack. Does this help?

> ```
> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-59-bf2539b2257e> in <module>
>       6 feature_vectors.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
>       7 feature_vectors
> ----> 8 sns.pairplot(feature_vectors, dropna=True )
>
> c:\program files\extensions\subpy_1.0.0.0\mc\lib\site-packages\seaborn\axisgrid.py
> ```
>
> in pairplot(data, hue, hue_order, palette, vars, x_vars, y_vars, kind,
>   diag_kind, markers, height, aspect, dropna, plot_kws, diag_kws,
>   grid_kws, size)
>          2105     if grid.square_grid:
>          2106         if diag_kind == "hist":
>       -> 2107             grid.map_diag(plt.hist, **diag_kws)
>          2108         elif diag_kind == "kde":
>          2109             diag_kws.setdefault("shade", True)
>
> ```
> c:\program files\extensions\subpy_1.0.0.0\mc\lib\site-packages\seaborn\axisgrid.py
> ```
>
> in map_diag(self, func, **kwargs)
>          1397                     color = fixed_color
>          1398 
>       -> 1399                 func(data_k, label=label_k, color=color, **kwargs)
>          1400 
>          1401             self._clean_axis(ax)
>
> ```
> c:\program files\extensions\subpy_1.0.0.0\mc\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py
> ```
>
> in hist(x, bins, range, density, weights, cumulative, bottom,
>   histtype, align, orientation, rwidth, log, color, label, stacked,
>   normed, data, **kwargs)
>          2659         align=align, orientation=orientation, rwidth=rwidth, log=log,
>          2660         color=color, label=label, stacked=stacked, normed=normed,
>       -> 2661         **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)
>          2662 
>          2663
>
> ```
> c:\program files\extensions\subpy_1.0.0.0\mc\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py
> ```
>
> in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
>          1808                         "the Matplotlib list!)" % (label_namer, func.**name**),
>          1809                         RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
>       -> 1810             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
>          1811 
>          1812         inner.**doc** = _add_data_doc(inner.**doc**,
>
> ```
> c:\program files\extensions\subpy_1.0.0.0\mc\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py
> ```
>
> in hist(self, x, bins, range, density, weights, cumulative, bottom,
>   histtype, align, orientation, rwidth, log, color, label, stacked,
>   normed, **kwargs)
>          6533         # Unit conversion is done individually on each dataset
>          6534         self._process_unit_info(xdata=x[0], kwargs=kwargs)
>       -> 6535         x = [self.convert_xunits(xi) for xi in x]
>          6536 
>          6537         if bin_range is not None:
>
> ```
> c:\program files\extensions\subpy_1.0.0.0\mc\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py
> ```
>
> in (.0)
>          6533         # Unit conversion is done individually on each dataset
>          6534         self._process_unit_info(xdata=x[0], kwargs=kwargs)
>       -> 6535         x = [self.convert_xunits(xi) for xi in x]
>          6536 
>          6537         if bin_range is not None:
>
> ```
> c:\program files\extensions\subpy_1.0.0.0\mc\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py
> ```
>
> in convert_xunits(self, x)
>           184         if ax is None or ax.xaxis is None:
>           185             return x
>       --> 186         return ax.xaxis.convert_units(x)
>           187 
>           188     def convert_yunits(self, y):
>
> ```
> c:\program files\extensions\subpy_1.0.0.0\mc\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py
> ```
>
> in convert_units(self, x)
>          1528             return x
>          1529 
>       -> 1530         ret = self.converter.convert(x, self.units, self)
>          1531         return ret
>          1532
>
> ```
> c:\program files\extensions\subpy_1.0.0.0\mc\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\category.py
> ```
>
> in convert(value, unit, axis)
>            51 
>            52         # force an update so it also does type checking
>       ---> 53         unit.update(values)
>            54 
>            55         str2idx = np.vectorize(unit._mapping.**getitem**,
>
> ```
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'
> ```

Comment: Hi @jenya56, welcome to StackOverflow! Please, provide detailed stacktrace (perhaps full, if it's not very large). At least, stacktrace should contain a number of the line where an error has occured. There's no explicit `update` in this part of your code, therefore, an error is somewhere inside

Comment: Hi, what is stacktrace:)? Thanks! It does point to pairplot line

Comment: See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47545540/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-update) where the user provided the full Traceback. But it's not guaranteed that this is enough. To ensure that someone is able to provide you with an answer, you should also provide a [mcve], i.e. the minimal *runnable* code that is needed to reproduce the error.

Comment: Hi, I just placed the full traceback in my original post. All your help is really appreciated!!!!